# how can i filter checked item from a list of available items in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter a list of item from a given list in reactjs and i have to pass the filtered list to redux store so that i can make it available in other component .
my list look something like this.
[image: list image]

> This is my code which I am not sure weather right or not

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleCheckboxChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked === true) {

      const filterd = cart.filter(c => c.checked);
      console.log('filterd', filterd);
      dispatch(checkItems(cart))

    } else {
      dispatch(uncheckItems(cart))
    }
  }

  return (
    cart.map(item => (
      <Grid
        style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid #d2d2d2" }}
        container
        className="margin15"
      >
        <Grid container spacing={16} justify="center" className="cart">
          <Grid container justify="flex-end" item xs={1}>
            <Checkbox
              onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
              style={{ padding: "0px" }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid className="image" item xs={6}>
            <img src={item.image._links.mainImage.href}></img>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4} container justify="space-around">
            <CartItemDetails cart={item} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

      </Grid>
    ))
  );
```

Comment: I think how you should do it is:

i. handleCheckboxChange(item.id)
ii. inside handleCheckboxChange your filter is alright but it doesn't know which you are clicking, therefore, you need to filter like so: 
const handleCheckboxChange = (id) => {
  cart.filter(item => item.id !== id); // this makes it check those that are not in this id, but it is not complete because it only works every 1 item you click and does not take into account the entire array.
}

You should have a state to manage this, for example:
this.state = {
  selected: []
};

Comment: after you initialize the this.state, inside handleCheckboxChange, you add the id into the `selected` array if it is not already inside, for example:
const item = cart.find(item => item.id);
this.setState({
  selected: [...selected, ...[item ? item : null]]
});

After you confirm that, you can go into the componentDidUpdate or if you're using hooks, you can do it in your useEffect.

Whenever the selected gets update, you dispatch with the new array

Comment: @kyapwc can u please write it in answer its hard to understand this way

Comment: Well, it should look something like this:

  this.state = {
    selected: cart.map(item => ({ ...item, checked: true })),
  };

  handleCheckboxChange(id, checked) {
    this.setState({
      selected: this.state.selected.map(item => {
        if (item.id === id) return { ...item, checked }
        return item;
      })
    })
  };

Comment: @kyapwc please add that in answer

Answer (score -2):

Well, it should look something like this:

```
this.state = {
  selected: cart.map(item => ({ ...item, checked: true }))
};

const handleCheckboxChange = (id, checked) => { 
this.setState({ 
selected: this.state.selected.map(item => {
  if (item.id === id) return { ...item, checked } 
    return item;
  }) 
 }) 
};

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.selected !== this.state.selected) {
    dispatch(this.state.selected);
  }
}
```